# Async functions with static variables?

Tags: c#, static, async-await

My apologies, I am now out of the office so I don't have the exact code, but I would appreciate some advice on the following situation.

**The situation**

I have a winform application with one button. (Well actually several but it can be reduced to one). 
This button calls a *series* of asynchronous operations. 
Every time this button is called, the set of operations it calls is assigned a unique serial number. (this operations involved some HttpClient operation)

If I press the button again before the first set of operations is finished, an error is expected to be returned.

*What I have*

```
  static int serialNumber=0;

 private async void button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   int old= serialNumber;
        serialNumber++;

       //Do some stuff
       //here and then

        var result= await callFirstOperation(serialNumber); 
        if(!result)
           {  serialNumber=old;
              return;
             }

       //Do some more stuff

        var result2= await callSecondOperation(serialNumber); 
         if(!result2)
           { serialNumber=old;
             return;
            }

        //Some more stuff and async operations   ....
       Trace.WriteLine("Fiuuu... finished!");  
    }
```

As you can see when the button is pressed a serial operation is used for the rest of asyn operations, but if one of them fail, the number is back to the old value.

This would not be a problem if I press the button and wait for the completion of everything, But what happens if I press the button twice, the second time before the first set of operations is finished.

I thing serial number will be affected (by the second call) which will affect also the following operations of the first set.

What is the correct way to implement the objective?

Can static variables be used safely somehow with async functions?

---

EDIT: 
I thought that not resetting the serial number would help but think about this

First Time button->  Serial Number:1

(First time) Operation1(1)

(First time) Operation2(1)

Then second time button-> Serial Number :2

(Second time) Operation 1(2) returns error

(First time) Operation3(2)<---WAIT! this should be 1 not 2!

Comment: why exactly did you decide to make `serialNumber` `static` ?

Comment: @MongZhu because the serial number has to be unique. I am not arguing it is the best approach at all though

Comment: as far as I understood, you want to inhibit the second pressing of the button before the entire algorithm has finished from the first time. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, I guess that even non static would present the same problem

Comment: yes, static is here not the problem. The declaration site (on class level) is what causes you trouble

Comment: " the serial number has to be unique." but do they have to be _consecutive_? If not, then there's no need to "reset" the serial number. just increment it, and if the operation fails, you have a gap in the numbers. IF that is not a big problem it will save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: @MongZhu actually not,I dont want to inhibit the pressing of the button. The asynchronous operation will automatically return an error so it will go to the `if (result)` part

Comment: @DStanley Actually I though about it as well but that would make it even more complicated. I will edit the question to explain (please wait)

Comment: If it's just about throwing an error when someone presses the button a second time before the first run can finish I suggest you using a mutex or semaphore to detect if a run is still going.

Comment: Whatever the reason, if you need to know if the prior operation is successful or not, then the simplest method is to make the call not be asynchronous. You at least have to wait until the last operation completes before starting a new one - perhaps with a queue?

Comment: @DStanley if I make it synchronous the GUI will freeze until completed. Not desirable

Comment: @RobinB so I have to use mutexes  with async? Any advice or example on how will be appreciated

Comment: a simple `bool ButtonAlreadyPressed` should suffice. Make it `true` in the beginning and `false` at the end. and perform the action only `if(!ButtonAlreadyPressed){... do async stuff }`

Comment: Why not give a visual feedback to the operator at the start of the procedure by disabling the button: ( (button)sender).Enabled = false; When finished, enable the button again. Or as Mong Zhu already said: remember that your procedure is started. If the same procedure is to be started again, show a MessageBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok as far as I understand your problem is that you want to prevent your program from running the async operations twice at the same time.

To do this you can use a semaphore.
This thread-safe structure works basically like a counter. Every time a thread enters it will count down. After it reaches 0 no more threads can enter and will have to wait.

```
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1);
```

This semaphore will allow 1 thread to enter and will be initialized with a count of 1.
To "enter" a semaphore protected chunk of code you call:

```
 semaphore.WaitOne()
```

This will decrement the counter by 1 and now prevent any task that also tries to call `WaitOne` to return from this call.

After this, you can be sure that only 1 task at a time will ever be in this section.

To open the semaphore for the next task you call:

```
  semaphore.Release();
```

For a better understanding I threw together a minimal example of this relating to your problem:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1);

  private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!semaphore.WaitOne(0))
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Long-running task hasn't finished yet!");

      return;
    }

    await LongRunningTask();

    semaphore.Release();
  }

  public async Task LongRunningTask()
  {
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    MessageBox.Show("Long running finished...");
  }
}
```

Special here is the call of `WaitOne(0)`. The first parameter (0) specifies that every task that wants to enter but can't because of a task already running. It will wait 0 milliseconds before returning. The trick here is that if it was denied entry `WaitOne` will return `false`. So we now know that there is already a task running and can terminate the second task which is done by the return.

I would also advise you to show this behavior by visual feedback to your user. For example by disabling the button as long as the actions are running as suggested in the comments above.